# Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child

Tags: react-native, touchablewithoutfeedback

When I use `TouchableOpacity` my code works fine, but when I use `TouchableWithoutFeedback` my code throws an error. As I don't want that blurred effect on click, I want to use `TouchableWithoutFeedback` instead.

```
return (
    <View  style={{ ...props.style}}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback   style={{...styles.row  }} onPress={toggleExpand}>
             <Text style={{ fontFamily : 'wiproakkurat-bold' , fontSize : RFValue(14) , color : '#434343' , paddingLeft : RFValue(18), ...props.styleText ,}}>{props.title}</Text>
             <Icon style={{paddingRight : RFValue(18)}} name={toggle.expanded ? 'keyboard-arrow-up' : 'keyboard-arrow-down'} size={RFValue(30)} color={'pink'} />
         </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

         <View style={styles.parentHr}/>
         {
             toggle.expanded &&
             <View style={styles.child}>
                 {props.data}  
             </View>
         }
    </View>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to show blur effect on click/touch. You can simply set **`activeOpacity={1}`** into 
**`<TouchableOpacity>`** tag

```
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1}>
<Text>Hello</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback) on `TouchableWithoutFeedback` says:

> TouchableWithoutFeedback supports only one child. If you wish to have several child components, wrap them in a View.

Indeed, `TouchableOpacity` does support multiple childs (hence why your code works when using that component), TouchableWithoutFeedback does not. However, you are giving TouchableWithoutFeedback multiple children components (`Text` and `Icon`), which isn't valid.
The solution should be to simply wrap the Text and Icon in a `View` component, or, if you don't want to use a View, a `React.Fragment`:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback   style={{...styles.row  }} onPress={toggleExpand}>
    <React.Fragment>
        <Text style={{ fontFamily : 'wiproakkurat-bold' , fontSize : RFValue(14) , color : '#434343' , paddingLeft : RFValue(18), ...props.styleText ,}}>{props.title}</Text>
        <Icon style={{paddingRight : RFValue(18)}} name={toggle.expanded ? 'keyboard-arrow-up' : 'keyboard-arrow-down'} size={RFValue(30)} color={'pink'} />
    </React.Fragment>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Comment: Your answer give me the explanation...but I have used another hack that solved my problem so I have to mark that answer accepted but your solution was also right :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use two or more elements in Touchables.
To solve your problem you must wrap your elements with `<View></View>` or `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>`
Like this:

```
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback   style={{...styles.row  }} onPress={toggleExpand}>
        <View>
              <Text style={{ fontFamily : 'wiproakkurat-bold' , fontSize : RFValue(14) , color : '#434343' , paddingLeft : RFValue(18), ...props.styleText ,}}>{props.title}</Text>
              <Icon style={{paddingRight : RFValue(18)}} name={toggle.expanded ? 'keyboard-arrow-up' : 'keyboard-arrow-down'} size={RFValue(30)} color={'pink'} />
        </View>
   </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Or

```
   <TouchableWithoutFeedback   style={{...styles.row  }} onPress={toggleExpand}>
        <React.Fragment>
              <Text style={{ fontFamily : 'wiproakkurat-bold' , fontSize : RFValue(14) , color : '#434343' , paddingLeft : RFValue(18), ...props.styleText ,}}>{props.title}</Text>
              <Icon style={{paddingRight : RFValue(18)}} name={toggle.expanded ? 'keyboard-arrow-up' : 'keyboard-arrow-down'} size={RFValue(30)} color={'pink'} />
        </React.Fragment>
   </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```